# Discord.js GUILD_VOICE_STATES

Tags: discord.js

In order to create a music bot on Discord, I must use the "GUILD_VOICE_STATES". But, when I run my code, I am being returned with this error: PlayerError: [PlayerError] client is missing "GUILD_VOICE_STATES" intent (at [all sorts of places]).

How do I fix this on repl.it?

If you wish to view my code: https://replit.com/@TylerLanier/Comusity-Bot#index.js

````
  intents: [
    "GUILDS"
    *"GUILD_VOICE_STATES"```*
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to set intents like this...

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')


const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES
  ]
})
```

[More on Intents Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Intents)